# Could it be that "chkrootkit" just doesn't like .hmac, .packlist, and .relocation-tag files?

Tags: centos, security, rootkit

I just cleaned up my hacked CentOS server (due to not updating since versino 5.3). But still, "chkrootkit" says this:

```
Possible t0rn v8 \(or variation\) rootkit installed

/usr/lib/.libfipscheck.so.1.1.0.hmac 
/usr/lib/.libgcrypt.so.11.hmac 
/usr/lib/.libfipscheck.so.1.hmac 
/lib/.libcrypto.so.0.9.8e.hmac 
/lib/.libssl.so.0.9.8e.hmac 
/lib/.libssl.so.6.hmac 
/lib/.libcrypto.so.6.hmac

/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/Text/Iconv/.packlist 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/.packlist 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/HTML-Tree/.packlist 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/Font/AFM/.packlist 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/MLDBM/Sync/.packlist 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/MLDBM/.packlist 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/FreezeThaw/.packlist
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/Apache/ASP/.packlist 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/HTML-Format/.packlist 

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/immodules/.relocation-tag 
/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2/.relocation-tag 
/usr/lib/python2.4/distutils/.relocation-tag 
/usr/lib/python2.4/config/.relocation-tag
```

Could it be that "chkrootkit" just doesn't like .hmac, .packlist, and .relocation-tag files?

Are these realy still infected?

Comment: Where did they come from? Who put them there? How do you know? If you can't answer that, since your system was compromised, it's best to wipe the whole thing and start over from scratch.

Comment: For example, I've just reinstalled perl - however, "chkrootkit" still reports those files.

Comment: Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Nuke it? Of course not. I've fixed nearly all problems. Along with an OS upgrade - good enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From www.chkrootkit.org:

"Q: chkrootkit is reporting some files and dirs as suspicious: .packlist,
.cvsignore, etc. These are clearly false positives. Can't you ignore
these?

A: Ignoring some files and dirs could impair chkrootkit's accuracy. An
attacker might use this, since he knows that chkrootkit will ignore certain
files and dirs."

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe at all in "cleaning up" a compromised server and consider the "nuke from orbit" option the only remedy.

Anyway, the only way to decide if these files are legitimate is to compare these files' checksums to those of known good files on a clean installation, but I think the fact that these library filenames are prepended by a `.` to hide them in a normal `ls` is more than enough reason to worry.